# How to show records related to upper records too in a subgrid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

How can I build a subgrid that displays related records both of the current record and records above it, and can it contain complex conditions ?

One of my requirements is this:

I want to put a subgrid in Account form showing the related Contacts of the current Account, and also include the Contacts related to Accounts *above* the current one *if* a Two Options attribute of the contact is set to *Yes*.

Specifically, I'm looking at the `Company Name` on Contact to establish it's related to an Account.

I'm at a loss and start to doubt it's doable.

Comment: Can you please clarify your entity model. Is it the following? `Account 1-M Contact` and `Account M-1 Account 1-M Contact`

Comment: @JamesWood Everything is standard

Comment: Still there are a couple of relationships, its not clear exactly which ones you are using.

Comment: @JamesWood That's right, amended

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve this considering that you can't do an "or" search with related entities

Answer (score 0):

Not an out of the box solution but if you don’t mind losing the sub grid command bar functionality you can use the following concept that [displays a fetchxml inside a sub-grid](http://totbcrm.blogspot.com/2014/08/display-custom-fetch-in-grid.html). 
Step 1 - would be to get all related accounts ids using a fetch or odata
Step 2 - construct a fetchxml with OR filter to get all contacts